# Oracle json path compound expression using multiple context does not work

Tags: json, oracle, jsonpath

I have the following json:

```
{
   "signedOffTasks":[
      "TASK2"
   ],
   "taskDeadlines":[
      {
         "taskKey":"TASK1",
         "deadline":"2016-05-02"
      },
      {
         "taskKey":"TASK2",
         "deadline":"2016-05-02"
      },
      {
         "taskKey":"TASK3",
         "deadline":"2016-05-02"
      },
      {
         "taskKey":"TASK4",
         "deadline":"2016-05-02"
      },
      {
         "taskKey":"TASK5",
         "deadline":"2016-05-02"
      },
      {
         "taskKey":"TASK6",
         "deadline":"2020-05-18"
      }
   ]
}
```

and the following json path expression:

```
$.taskDeadlines[?(@.deadline == "2020-05-18" && $.signedOffTasks.indexOf(@.taskKey) == -1)]
```

that is I want to return something where the deadline is 2020-05-18, and the appropriate task key is not in the signedOffTasks array.

This works very well in

https://codebeautify.org/jsonpath-tester

but unfortunately, if I use the same JSON in an Oracle 12c CLOB column, Oracle does not allow me to mix contexts. It has problems with the $ in the second predicate.

How can I express what I want with Oracle Json path implementation?

This is how I want to make the Oracle query:

```
SELECT
     *
 FROM
     TABLE MY_TABLE T
 WHERE
    JSON_EXISTS ( T.JSON_COLUMN,'$.taskDeadlines[?(@.deadline == "2020-05-18" && $.signedOffTasks.indexOf(@.taskKey) == -1)]')
```

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you calling the JSON expression in your SQL statement?

Comment: @ChrisSaxon I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexOf` method is unsupported (as of [Oracle Database 19c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-8656CAB9-C293-4A99-BB62-F38F3CFC4C13)). So you can't use this to check if the task exists within `signedOffTasks`.

I'm not sure how you'd write this using JSON path expressions in Oracle Database. But it's possible with SQL!

You can convert the arrays to rows-and-columns using `json_table`:

```
select j.* from t, json_table (
  c1, '$.taskDeadlines[*]'
  columns (
    taskKey path '$.taskKey',
    deadline path '$.deadline'
  )
) j
where  deadline = '2020-05-18';

TASKKEY    DEADLINE     
TASK6      2020-05-18  

select j.* from t, json_table (
  c1, '$.signedOffTasks[*]'
  columns (
    task path '$'
  )
) j;

TASK    
TASK2
```

From there you could use `not exists`/`minus` to return the deadline tasks not in the signed off array:

```
select j.taskKey from t, json_table (
  c1, '$.taskDeadlines[*]'
  columns (
    taskKey path '$.taskKey',
    deadline path '$.deadline'
  )
) j
where  deadline = '2020-05-18'
minus
select j.task from t, json_table (
  c1, '$.signedOffTasks[*]'
  columns (
    task path '$'
  )
) j;

TASKKEY   
TASK6
```

---

It's a little fiddly, but you can do this all in the `where` clause if needed:

```
select * from t
where  exists (
  select * from json_table (
    c1, '$.taskDeadlines[*]'
    columns (
      taskKey path '$.taskKey',
      deadline path '$.deadline'
    )  
  ) j1
  where  deadline = '2020-05-18'
  and    not exists ( 
    select * from json_table (
      c1, '$.signedOffTasks[*]'
      columns (
        task path '$'
      )
    ) j2
    where  j1.taskKey = j2.task
  )
);

C1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
{
   "signedOffTasks":[
      "TASK2"
   ],
   "taskDeadlines":[ ...
```

Comment: That looks nice, but unfortunately, my query is programmatically generated, and I cannot mess with anything apart from the where clause. Meaning the whole thing must be contained in a WHERE clause fragment

Comment: You can do these conversions in `(not) exists`, so you can place them in `where` if needed; see example added

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking time with this!

Comment: I wonder why this doesn't work in 12c, but works in 18c express

Comment: It's not even an Oracle error it is: "No more data to read from socket"

Comment: deadline = '2020-05-18' I have converted this to actual date and now it works...